# How can I annotate a web article?

Tags: website, reference-managers

More generally, what "workflow" do people suggest when dealing with web articles in research?

I used to always save useful articles as PDFs to my Documents folder, and maybe copy and paste useful information I found to a word processor document. I have realized this is inefficient for a number of reasons, and found simply bookmarking useful articles and organizing those bookmarks in a nested file system (in Safari) to be a more elegant, clean work process.
Is there any similar minimalist process for annotating those web articles? I know Evernote and others have a web annotator, but I'm hesitant to deal with external software... a feature integrated into Safari would be ideal.

Can anyone recommend how they deal with web articles when researching?

Comment: Zotero might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Or Mendeley or Endnote or Jabref or Citavi ...

Comment: Isn't that a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ rather than this site? Actually, it might even be a duplicate : https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2959/30773

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Microsoft OneNote. When you copy content from a website and paste it into a notebook, OneNote automatically appends the website URL. You can thus collect all relevant snippets without losing track of where they came from, and add your thoughts there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hypothes.is](https://web.hypothes.is/) tool. It is an open tool created by a non-profit to annotate freely on the web. They have a browsed add-on that you can download. You can even share your annotations (if organising a journal club).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and welcome to academia.se! Just to avoid doubts, keep in mind that, in case you are associated with the tool you are suggesting, you should disclose it in your answer.

Comment: Good point. I am not associated with Hypothes.is. I know this tool from presentations at publishing meetings that I have attended. It seems to be a good idea for commonly annotating documents - for example in a class. It does not even have to apply to science - my friend uses it to annotate travel plans with her partner when the go on holidays, marking museums they want to see on Wikitravel, etc. I personally have not used it before, so I give you that.

Comment: OK, perfect. I apologize for having had doubts, but in the past we have had a few new users that posted on this site just to advertise their own products.

Comment: it is a valid concern, and I did post an answer just a couple of hours ago about the tool that I personally work on without mentioning that in the post - changed it after your comment. Still think that sometimes it is ok to make people aware of the new tools, but disclosing conflict of interest is simply a good practice and an ethical thing to do